# Perforce and Business Mashups Integration

Tags: perforce, serena

I know it is a specific topic to ask, but I thought that there might be someone who has dealt with this issue.

I have started to work on integrating [Serena Business Mashups](http://www.serena.com/products/sbm/) with Perforce.

I was just wondering whether anyone on the site has done it before.

Where do I need to start? Have you used the Perforce integration SDK? Or is it better to write from scratch?

I would be really thankful if you could share your experiences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I work for Perforce.)

I've not used these products directly, but Serena and a couple of consulting companies offer integrations between SBM and Perforce.  You could try contacting them directly for more information.

The links are on Perforce's integrations list: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/defecttracking_table.html

I'd post them directly but I don't want to flood you with links...

Comment: Serena Business Mashups connector does not support p4 2010.2 version which we are currently use. And I really do not want to pay st**id amount of money doe professional service as we have skills to implement our own connector. The problem is insufficiency of the documentation... Support of p4 is cool and easy to get reply, unlike p4, Serena Support is not always helpful for this type of problems ans it is out of their scope. I think I need to start looking at implementing the connector from scratch... thanks.

Comment: @AnarchistGeek If you want to roll your own, then I would look at Perforce's Defect Tracking Gateway.  It has an integration framework and example code which could save you time versus starting from scratch.